# CoreAudio, iOS: Failed to use mono Input and stereo output with RemoteIO

Tags: ios, core-audio, remoteio

I was trying to set audio input to mono and output to stereo using two `AudioStreamBasicDescription`s for one RemoteIO AudioUnit, which is the only AudioUnit there.

Then I registered two separate callbacks for input (`kAudioOutputUnitProperty_SetInputCallback`) and output (`kAudioUnitProperty_SetRenderCallback`), and expect that in my output callback, with `AudioBufferList *ioData`, `ioData->mNumberBuffers` should be 2.

But, to my surprise, it is still 1.

Is it that RemoteIO does not support having different channel numbers for input and output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seemed to have figured it out:
I was using signed-integer sample format, and with that format, 
the input argument `AudioBufferList *ioData` of the RenderCallback has only one AudioBuffer in it with interleaved audio samples (two output channel buffers concatenated into one), i.e.,  the `AudioBufferList::mNumberBuffers` is one. Its only `AudioBuffer` member in turn has an attribute `mNumberChannels` which corresponds to the true channel count. In my case, that field is two.

An additional finding to support the above: Signed-integer format cannot be interleaved (tested with Xcode4.6 on OSX Mountain Lion), i.e., the property `kAudioFormatFlagIsNonInterleaved` cannot be combined with `kAudioFormatFlagIsSignedInteger` when setting the format flag of the ASBD.

If using float plus non-interleaved sample format, the `AudioBufferList *ioData` of the RenderCallback has two `AudioBuffer`s in the buffer list, each has the `mNumberChannels` field as one.